# Why does my Webcam keep displaying an error

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing a personal project where I would be able to put an image onto the canvas and save it in my library. This works when I am uploading a .png from the browse button, But when I try to take a webcam image it does not.

All that happens is my "error divider" keeps on popping up in place of the camera output. Can someone spot the error? I've been working on this for days. Probably just need a fresh perspective.

**webcam.js**

```
var video = document.querySelector("#webcam");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var button = document.getElementById("pickImage");
var miniatures = document.getElementById("miniatures");
var inputFile = document.getElementById("take-picture");
var pickFile = document.getElementById("pickFile");
var notAvailable = document.getElementById("camera-not-available");

var cadre = document.getElementById("cadre");
var cigarette = document.getElementById("cigarette");
var hat = document.getElementById("hat");

var cameraAvailable = false;

var promisifiedOldGUM = function(constraints) {

  var getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.oGetUserMedia);

  if(!getUserMedia) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
  }

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
  });
}

if(navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices = {};
}

if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = promisifiedOldGUM;
}

var constraints = {video: true};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(handleVideo)
.catch(videoError);

function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    cameraAvailable = true;
    video.style.display = "block";
    notAvailable.style.display = "none";
    button.onclick = function() {
      var image = new Image();
      canvas.style.display = "none";
      pickFile.style.display = "none";

      image.addEventListener("load", function() {
          if (file === "cadre.png") {
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1024, 768, 0, 0, 640, 480);
          } else if (file === "cigarette.png") {
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1024, 768, 100, 200, 240, 180);
          } else {
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1024, 768, 180, 0, 240, 180);
          }
      }, false);

      image.src = document.querySelector('input[name="img"]:checked').value; // Set source path
      var split = image.src.split("/");
      var file = split[split.length - 1];

            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, 640, 480);
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0) && xhr.responseText != null && xhr.responseText != "") {
          var newImg = document.createElement("IMG");
          newImg.className = "icon removable";
          newImg.src = "montage/" + xhr.responseText;
          newImg.onclick = function(event) {
            var pathToImg = event.srcElement.src;
            var srcTab = pathToImg.split('/');
            var src = srcTab[srcTab.length - 1];

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0) && xhr.responseText == "OK") {
                miniatures.removeChild(event.srcElement);
              }
            };
            xhr.open("POST", "./forms/removemontage.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send("src=" + src);
          }
          miniatures.appendChild(newImg);
            }
      };
      xhr.open("POST", "./forms/montage.php", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.send("img=" + "../img/" + file + "&f=" + img);
        };
}

function videoError(e) {
    cameraAvailable = false;
    video.style.display = "none";
    notAvailable.style.display = "block";
}

function onCheckBoxChecked(checkbox) {
  if (cameraAvailable) {
      button.style.display = "block";
      if (checkbox.id === "cadre.png") {
        cadre.style.display = "block";
        cigarette.style.display = "none";
        hat.style.display = "none";
      } else if (checkbox.id === "cigarette.png") {
        cadre.style.display = "none";
        cigarette.style.display = "block";
        hat.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        cadre.style.display = "none";
        cigarette.style.display = "none";
        hat.style.display = "block";
      }
  }
  inputFile.style.display = "block";
  if (inputFile.files.length) {
    var image = new Image();
    var img = new Image();
    image.addEventListener("load", function() {
        canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        var data64Img = canvas.toDataURL(image.type);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file);

        img.src = document.querySelector('input[name="img"]:checked').value; // Set source path
        var split = img.src.split("/");
        var file = split[split.length - 1];

        if (file === "cadre.png") {
          canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1024, 768, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        } else if (file === "cigarette.png") {
          canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1024, 768, 100, 200, 240, 180);
        } else {
          canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1024, 768, 180, 0, 240, 180);
        }

        pickFile.onclick = function () {
          sendMontage(data64Img, file);
        }
    }, false);
    image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(inputFile.files[0]);
  }
}


function sendMontage(imgData64, filterImg) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0) && xhr.responseText != null && xhr.responseText != "") {
      var newImg = document.createElement("IMG");
      newImg.className = "icon removable";
      newImg.src = "montage/" + xhr.responseText;
      newImg.onclick = function(event) {
        var pathToImg = event.srcElement.src;
        var srcTab = pathToImg.split('/');
        var src = srcTab[srcTab.length - 1];

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0) && xhr.responseText == "OK") {
            miniatures.removeChild(event.srcElement);
          }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "./forms/removemontage.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("src=" + src);
      }
      miniatures.appendChild(newImg);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "./forms/montage.php", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("img=" + "../img/" + filterImg + "&f=" + imgData64);
}
```

This is my webcam.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("functions/montage.php");

$montages = get_all_montage();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/gallery.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CAMAGRU - gallery</title>
  </header>
  <body>
    <?php include('fragments/header.php') ?>
      <div class="body">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>
        <div class="main">
              <div class="select">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="img/cadre.png"></img>
                <input id="cadre.png" type="radio" name="img" value="./img/cadre.png" onclick="onCheckBoxChecked(this)">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="img/cigarette.png"></img>
                <input id="cigarette.png" type="radio" name="img" value="./img/cigarette.png" onclick="onCheckBoxChecked(this)">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="img/hat.png"></img>
                <input id="hat.png" type="radio" name="img" value="./img/hat.png" onclick="onCheckBoxChecked(this)">
              </div>
          <video width="100%" autoplay="true" id="webcam"></video>
          <div id="camera-not-available">CAMERA NOT AVAILABLE</div>
          <img id="hat" style="display:none;" src="img/hat.png"></img>
          <img id="cigarette" style="display:none;" src="img/cigarette.png"></img>
          <img id="cadre" style="display:none;" src="img/cadre.png"></img>
              <div class="capture" id="pickImage">
            <img class="camera" src="img/camera.png"></img>
          </div>
          <canvas id="canvas" style="display:none;" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
          <div class="captureFile" id="pickFile">
            <img class="camera" src="img/camera.png"></img>
          </div>
          <input type="file" id="take-picture" style="display:none;" accept="image/*">
        </div>
        <div class="side">
            <div class="title">Montages</div>
      <div id="miniatures">
        <?php
          $gallery = "";
          if ($montages != null) {
            for ($i = 0; $montages[$i] ; $i++) {
              $class = "icon";
              if ($montages[$i]['userid'] === $_SESSION['id']) {
                $class .= " removable";
              }
              $gallery .= "<img class=\"" . $class . "\" src=\"./montage/" . $montages[$i]['img'] . "\" data-userid=\"" . $montages[$i]['userid'] . "\"></img>";
            }
            echo $gallery;
          }
        ?>
      </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
          You need to connect to use the gallery
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    <?php include('fragments/footer.php') ?>
  </body>
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webcam.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/drop.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/import.js"></script>
  <?php } ?>
</HTML>
```

for the sake of not overloading the page, ive left out any unnecesary files where the error is most likely not to be.

Comment: I've traced the problem to those 2 pages. It would seem that something in my javascript is flawed.

Comment: It seems like a permission issue.

Comment: @Raghul Shree it does have full permission from the browser though. and a simplified version of this does indeed work.